# How to explain the topic of Fourier transform interactively?

Tags: soft-question, fourier-analysis, transformation, education

This is a soft question . In the walk-in for the lectureship, I have decided to give demo lecture on the topic of **Fourier transform**.

The principal of the institution ask me to take lecture  interactively with students on the given topic for **around 20 to 25 minutes**.  I should teach them interactively by which they can learn Fourier transform with interest.

But I could not dare to counter question him **"How to make and teach Fourier transform topic interactive one?"** ;-)

Now,I am confused with what should be the start of the lecture? Should I take any example or any application than directly coming on equations or any other ?

What  should I tell about importance of Fourier transform? The important factors of signals I.e. phase,frequency and amplitude ? So can anybody help me for it?

Comment: You could use sock puppets. One sock puppet could propose building up a large class of periodic functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ from sines and cosines, and a large class of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ from integral "sums" of sines and cosines. Then the other sock puppets could beat up the first socket puppet and keep it from publishing for 20 years. That would be a good accurate way to teach the History of the subject.

Comment: Consider asking this at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).  If you do so, please link to this question.